# chart.js how to remove border

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to remove the border from my chart:

[image]

You can't see it but there is also the border for x axis.

I tried:

scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)" and

drawBorder: false,

on the grid, but the black border is still there, can you help me?
I'm using chart.js 4.3.0

```
const AreaChart = () => {
  const chartContainer = useRef(null);
  const data = [1,2,3];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartContainer.current) {
      const ctx = chartContainer.current.getContext("2d");

      const labels = ["Today","Day 2"];

      const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data",
              data: data,
              fill: true,
            },
          ],
        },
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        options: {
          scales: {
            x: {
              grid: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false,
                color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
              },
            },
            y: {
              grid: {
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false,
                color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });

    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", margin: "0 auto" }}>
      <canvas ref={chartContainer} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AreaChart;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use border: {display: false} for each axis:

```
...
   scales: {
          x: {
            border: {
              display: false,
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
              color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
            },
          },
          y: {
            border: {
              display: false,
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
              color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
            },
          },
        },
```